# what is the method and attribute in python module

Tags: python-3.x, module

I am a beginner for programming. My question may be a stupid question.can anyone answer my questions..

what is the method in python module?
method= name,function      is this right?
and what is the attribute in python module?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentations, check this. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#